# Specific Regex In Javascript for fields

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

It consists of a string of 7 numeric digits. The string is preceded by two or three characters and ends with a single character. There should be no character space within the entire string

```
function  Country(country) {
  var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
  var letters = /^\d{7}?$/;
  if ( country =="" || country.match(letters)) {
    text="";
    message[4].innerHTML = text;
    return true;
  }
  
  else {
    text="Country name should contain only letters";
    message[4].innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following regex to become a string with two or three alphabetic letters at the begin, in the middle three numbers and at the end one alphabetic letter!

```regex
^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1}$
```

Comment: I want a regex who can validate string like abc789a only. Mean total 7 length first three are alphabets. Next three digits and last one alphabet

Comment: Okay, I have edit my answer as you wish. But your question isn't clear, but with this comment you make it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

> It consists of a string of 7 numeric digits.

```
var isSeven = country.length===7;
```

> The string is preceded by
> two or three characters and ends with a single character.

```
var isCountry = /^[a-z]{2,3}\d+[a-z]{1}$/i;
```

if we combine the two conditions we reach the pattern:
***digits deponds on letters***
*Numbers of letters Three, therefore Numbers of digits Three like you suggest in comment 'abc789a'.*
*Numbers of letters Two,consequently Numbers of digits Four 'ab6789a'.*

> There should be no character space within the entire string.

```
var hasNoSpace = /[^\s]/g;
```

finally

```
    return isCountry.test(country) && isSeven && hasNoSpace.test(country)
```